# Lower bound of the $\Lambda(\Gamma)$-rank of the dual Selmer group of an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am facing a problem in the proof of theorem 2.6 on page 23 in Coates and Sujathas "Galois Cohomology of elliptic curves".

Let F be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, p a prime in $\mathbb{Q}$ and v a place in F such that v does not divide p. We denote $K_{\infty,w}$ for the union of the completions at w of all finite extension of F contained in $K_\infty$.  They state that by Proposition 2 in Greenbergs "Iwasawa theory of p-adic representations" $\widehat{H^1(K_{\infty,w},E_{p^\infty})}$ is $\Lambda(\Gamma)$-torsion.

I don't understand how they deduce it from Proposition 2.